# Testing Django Facebook App

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-testing

I'm making a Django app with Fandjango and I'm trying to unit test it with Django's test framework. The only thing is, in order to test effectively I need a "signed_request" parameter that Facebook sends with every request. Right now I'm logging the requests my server gets from Facebook and copying + pasting the signed_request token I get, but that only works for a few hours at a time.

Is there a simple way to handle this without doing a mock of the whole Facebook API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Test Users: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

I think the access token never expires, or at less until you delete the Test User.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I understand it's also possible to authenticate fully server side, using just OAuth without Javascript SDK. In that case you should be able to aquire a valid token yourself. There are, I think some libraries that can be used for that like:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth/

However please note, I've never done this myself so it's more of a suggestion, than a definite answer.

*EDIT*

It seems like social-auth has some testing functionality that is capable of automatically signing in to a facebook account. You could probably copy the code from there.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this quite addresses the problem I'm having. The problem I have is that the requests to my server are actually coming from Facebook with a signed payload, "signed_request". When I simulate these requests during testing, I'd like to just include the "signed_request" along with my calls so my app properly communicates with Facebook.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being confusing, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me either. I have used Graph API with no trouble in the past, but this is different.